# Not able to parse Jsoncpp object received in 0MQ socket

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, zeromq, jsoncpp

I am building a server and client in c++ which use ZeroMQ PAIR sockets to communicate. Since I want to call some RPC from client to server, I am using JSON::Value structure to encode the function name and arguments, so that the server can parse it and call the appropriate function.

I checked out gRPC for doing the same but I felt it as an overkill as it requires too much effort to get it right.

As a draft, I am created a sample client and server apps. I am able to send the data from client to server, but on the server side I am receiving parse error. Could anyone suggest me what I might be doing wrong?

client.cpp

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <jsoncpp/json/value.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/reader.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/writer.h>
int main ()
{
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_PAIR);
    /**
     * Json object value parser
    */
    Json::Value out;
    Json::Value res;
    Json::StreamWriterBuilder builder;

    out["MESSAGE"] = "Anaconda";
    out["NEWS"] = "Something is wrong";

    std::cout << "Connecting to hello world server…" << std::endl;
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555");

    zmq::message_t request(out.size());
    std::string str = Json::writeString(builder, out);
    std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
    memcpy (request.data(),&str, out.size());
    socket.send (request);

    //  Get the reply.
    zmq::message_t reply;
    socket.recv (&reply);
    return 0;
}
```

server.cpp

```
    int main () {
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_PAIR);
    socket.bind ("tcp://*:5555");
    /**
     * Json object value parser
    */
    Json::Reader mReader = {};
    Json::Value res;

    while (true) {
        zmq::message_t request;
        //  Wait for next request from client
        socket.recv (&request);
        std::string str = std::string(static_cast<char*>(request.data()), request.size());
        std::cout <<str<<std::endl;
        auto ok = mReader.parse(str, res);
        if (!ok) {
            std::cout <<"ConHash:: Error while parsing: %s "<< mReader.getFormattedErrorMessages().c_str() << std::endl;
            return false;
        } else {
            std::cout<<"Successfully parsed !!" <<std::endl;
        }
        //  Do some 'work'
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also could you please advice me is there any other better way to make RPC from client to server?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the size of the `Json::Value` out object as the size to send over the socket. This is incorrect, you need to use the size of the newly created string.

Change the code to:

```
std::string str = Json::writeString(builder, out);
zmq::message_t request(str.c_str(), str.size());
socket.send (request);
```